# Debug thread safety issue on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, thread-safety

I've got a thread safety bug somewhere in a fairly large set of code. It's reproducible as a random crash simply by scrolling around in my `CATiledLayer` for a few seconds in the simulator, and solvable by locking my drawing code into a single thread (which is not ideal, since CATiledLayer is designed to be multi-threaded and my drawing code is slow enough to need it).

How do I go about debugging a thread safety issue? I suspect it's somewhere in my code to lazily fetch (and cache) the data which is being drawn, but that doesn't narrow it down much.

I've skim read the Concurrency Programming Guide, but don't see anything that talks about debugging, it just talks about how to structure your code.

Comment: Replace the "code to lazily fetch (and cache) the data which is being drawn" with simpler code that simply spins for a while and returns a static image?

Comment: The data is a couple of gigabytes of vector data (maps). I can't store all of it in RAM, and it wouldn't even fit on an iOS device at all if it was a bitmap image instead of vector.

Comment: It doesn't need to return actual data; it should be a *simple* method that returns dummy data (ideally taking approximately as much time/CPU as returning "real" data) to see if it's a problem in the original method.

Answer (score 1):

Which concurrency method do you use? GCD or NSThread? And if I can't convince you to use single thread for drawing, try to use `@syncronized` in your setter/getter methods (or atomic properties, if you use synthesized setters/getters).

Comment: I don't know what concurrency method is being used, but probably GCD. CATiledLayer is doing all of that, and instructing me to draw into one tile at a time on each physical CPU core (it's a single background thread on an A4 CPU, which is why I didn't discover the bug until after writing a ton of code). According to the documentation, all of core graphics is thread safe, and as far as I know all of my code to access the data is also thread safe (I'm using dispatch_sync where it isn't), but obviously there is a bug. Surely there is some technique other than reading all my code? That'd take days.

Comment: Well, you could try profiling (Instruments) and look for memory leaks and zombies. And since you use GCD's dispatch_sync, do you know, that multiple queues can have same name? So when you launch dispatch_sync, if you create queue within the dispatch_sync instruction, you basically create another thread. Workaround is to create queue manager that persists all the time during your application runtime, which holds references to all pre-created queues for your animations.